# ElasticSearch Count API ,multiple counts as one request in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Is it possible to do a count on multiple indexes with different query filters in one request ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-count.html

Something like this : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-multi-search.html

But then for the Count API.
There is a multi-index option , but that will just sum the hits and will not work when the inital count query-filters are different.

```
$this->client = ClientBuilder::fromConfig(SOME_CONFIG);

$results1 =$this->client->count($SomeQueryOnIndex1);
$results2 =$this->client->count($SomeQueryOnIndex2);
$results3 =$this->client->count($SomeQueryOnIndex3);

// Would love to reduce those 3 requests to one.
$mergedQueries = $SomeQueryOnIndex1 +$SomeQueryOnIndex2 + $SomeQueryOnIndex3

//  Something like this ...
$results = $this>client->mcount($mergedQueries);

//..and then have for each index/query the number of hits.
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: I'd use the `_msearch` API with `size: 0`

Comment: @Val I don't know the inner workings of ElasticSearch , but is the Count API just a size 0 request , or do they request the data differently and is it optimized for performance.  That is what I am in the end looking for ...